# Timer counter directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i've written this example hover counter directive in angularjs. It works, and writes the number of seconds to the console. It renders "Hover Me 0" but doesn't update the number while its counting.

```
angular.directive('countHoverTime', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.seconds = 0;
      var ticking = false;

      var tickTock = function() {
        scope.seconds++;
        console.log( 'tick' );
        if (ticking) {
          window.setTimeout( tickTock, 1000 );
        }
      }

      $(element).hover( function() {
        console.log('Hover In');
        scope.seconds = 0;
        ticking = true;
        tickTock();
      }, function() {
        console.log('Hover Out');
        ticking = false;
        console.log("Seconds: " + scope.seconds);
      });

    }
  };
});
```

And html

```
<p count-hover-time>Hover me! {{ seconds }} </p>
```

Comment: i liked apairet's comment about angularizing instead of jquery for .hover but i still need to call scope.$apply() to make the dom update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before console log write this statement

```
 scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

For the changes to the model are reflected in the view, you need tell angular that made a change.

You should use `$scope.$apply();` to do it.

```js
angular.module('so',[])

.directive('countHoverTime', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.seconds = 0;
      var ticking = false;

      var tickTock = function() {
        scope.seconds++;
        scope.$apply();
        console.log( 'tick' );
        if (ticking) {
          window.setTimeout( tickTock, 1000 );
        }
      }

      $(element).hover( function() {
        console.log('Hover In');
        scope.seconds = 0;
        ticking = true;
        tickTock();
      }, function() {
        console.log('Hover Out');
        ticking = false;
        console.log("Seconds: " + scope.seconds);
      });

    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="so">
<p count-hover-time>Hover me! {{ seconds }} </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using jQuery to handle the 'hover' event. Angular thus has no idea to know scope.seconds changed and connot update the view accordingly. If you want to continue using jQuery notation (ie `$(element).hover( function() {...`, you have to call `scope.$apply()` to force a digest cycle.

I would suggest fixing your by changing

```
$(element).hover(...)
```

to an angular notation:

```
element.hover(...)
```

Since you include jQuery, this is equivalent as `$(element)` but it is 'angularized'
See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element for more info!